# Solving $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{xy+3x-2y+6}{xy-3x-2y+6}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm stuck with this problem...

$$\frac{\operatorname{d}y}{\operatorname{d}x} = \frac{xy+3x-2y+6}{xy-3x-2y+6}$$

I have tried separating variables in the following way:

$$\frac{\operatorname{d}y}{\operatorname{d}x} = \frac{x(y+3)2(-y+3)}{y(x-2)3(-x+2)}$$

$$\left(\frac{y+3 \cdot 2(-y+3)}{y}\right)\operatorname{d}y = \left(\frac{x-2 \cdot 3(-x+2)}{x}\right)\operatorname{d}x$$

$$\left(\frac{-y+9}{y}\right) \operatorname{d}y = \left(\frac{-2x+4}{x}\right) \operatorname{d}x$$

Then integrating both sides I end up with
$$y=2x+\ln\left(\frac{y^9}{x^4}\right)+C$$

I'd appreciate very much if someone give me the right answer because I don't know if my solution is correct or not. Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a [$\tt MSE\ MathJax\ Tutorial$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in this site. Your questions will have nice looking and it'll increase the possibility of answers. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, for the info, I'll check it out. It's my first time posting

Comment: I have not double checked the solution, but one thing you can always do is plug your solution into the original equation, and see if it's satisfied! The nice thing about differential equations is that, while they might be hard to solve, verification of a solution is usually easy :)

Comment: I just edited your first line such that you can see it as an example. Thanks.

Comment: Your algebra is incorrect. $xy+3x-2y+6$ equals $x(y+3)+2(-y+3)$, which is certainly not the same as $x(y+3) \cdot 2(-y+3)$.

Comment: Presumably you meant to write $xy + 3x - 2y + 6 = x(y+3) - 2(y-3)$ and $xy - 3x - 2y + 6 = x(y-3) - 2(y-3) = (x-2)(y-3)$. The numerator cannot be factorized as you seem to have done.

Comment: Ok I just realized my algebra is not correct, I'll fix that and try again. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{align}\frac{xy+3x-2y+6}{xy-3x-2y+6}&=\frac{6x+xy-3x-2y+6}{xy-3x-2y+6}\\
&=\frac{6x+x(y-3)-2(y-3)}{x(y-3)-2(y-3)}\\
&=\frac{6x+(x-2)(y-3)}{(x-2)(y-3)}\\
&=\frac{6x}{(x-2)(y-3)}+1\\
\end{align}$

So, your non-linear ODE is
$$y'=\frac{6x}{(x-2)(y-3)}+1$$
or
$$(y-3)(y'-1)=\frac{6x}{x-2}.$$
If we make a change of variable $u=y-3$ then $y'=u'$ and hence we have
$$uu'-u=\frac{6x}{x-2}.$$
I don't now how to solve it. WA couldn't solve too. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=yy%27-y%3D6x%2F%28x-2%29
I need to unlock pro-wa?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I corrected my algebra and ended up with $\left(\frac{-y+3}{y+3}\right) \operatorname{d}y = \left(\frac{x}{x-2}\right)-\left(\frac{2}{x-2}\right) \operatorname{d}x $ which is one on the x side

Then I integrated both sides and my answer was $y=x-6ln\left({y+3}\right)+C$

I think that is the final answer because I plugged it in the simplified equation and it equals 1, and the derivative of my answer is also 1.
Correct me if I'm wrong, please, and thanks for your answer

Comment: WA says it is Chini's equation.